# call program and bash.sh from info.plist

Tags: macos

I have a current Mac os x application, how do I modify info.plist file to include execution of update.sh script as well as program itself?

I have made update.sh and put it MacOS folder inside .app, I also added one more executable via:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>update.sh</string>
```

but it seems that It does not getting executed (just the program launches, but script is not executed).

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that. It works here. `update.sh` must be inside `Yourapp.app/Contents/MacOS` and it must be executable (`chmod +x` the file).